# AMD Ryzen ThreadRipper's home server continues to shut down

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxmox

My home server specification

- AMD RYZEN Threadripper PRO 5955WX
- ASUS PRO WS WRX80E-SAGE SE WIFI
- SAMSUNG DDR4 64GB * 8
- Corsair HX750 80PLUS PLATINUM

Install the above specification, installation with the Ubuntu 220.4 LXC and configured words to the container.

There is no problem when you boot the LXC controller, there is no problem when you boot. Booter container and operate a Docker container container and operate a Docker container container container, and then the following error occurs.

```
Feb 25 02:17:01 v4 CRON[35659]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)  
Feb 25 02:17:01 v4 CRON[35660]: (root) CMD ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)  
Feb 25 02:17:01 v4 CRON[35659]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root  
Feb 25 02:21:37 v4 kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged  
Feb 25 02:21:37 v4 kernel: [Hardware Error]: Corrected error, no action required.  
Feb 25 02:21:37 v4 kernel: [Hardware Error]: CPU:1 (19:8:2) MC1_STATUS[Over|CE|MiscV|-|-|-|SyndV|-|-|-]: 0xd8200000060a0859  
Feb 25 02:21:37 v4 kernel: [Hardware Error]: PPIN: 0x02b68f671f2d007b  
Feb 25 02:21:37 v4 kernel: [Hardware Error]: IPID: 0x000100b000000000, Syndrome: 0x000000005a000586  
Feb 25 02:21:37 v4 kernel: [Hardware Error]: Instruction Fetch Unit Ext. Error Code: 10, L1 BTB Multi-Match Error.  
Feb 25 02:21:37 v4 kernel: [Hardware Error]: cache level: L1, mem/io: IO, mem-tx: IRD, part-proc: SRC (no timeout)  
Feb 25 02:24:34 v4 pmxcfs[1191]: [dcdb] notice: data verification successful  
Feb 25 02:31:05 v4 pvedaemon[1316]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'  
Feb 25 02:46:30 v4 pvedaemon[1317]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'  
Feb 25 02:52:45 v4 kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged  
Feb 25 02:52:45 v4 kernel: [Hardware Error]: Corrected error, no action required.  
Feb 25 02:52:45 v4 kernel: [Hardware Error]: CPU:1 (19:8:2) MC1_STATUS[Over|CE|MiscV|-|-|-|SyndV|-|-|-]: 0xd8200000060a0859  
Feb 25 02:52:45 v4 kernel: [Hardware Error]: PPIN: 0x02b68f671f2d007b  
Feb 25 02:52:45 v4 kernel: [Hardware Error]: IPID: 0x000100b000000000, Syndrome: 0x000000005a000581  
Feb 25 02:52:45 v4 kernel: [Hardware Error]: Instruction Fetch Unit Ext. Error Code: 10, L1 BTB Multi-Match Error.  
Feb 25 02:52:45 v4 kernel: [Hardware Error]: cache level: L1, mem/io: IO, mem-tx: IRD, part-proc: SRC (no timeout)
Feb 25 03:03:38 v4 pvedaemon[1315]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'  
Feb 25 03:10:01 v4 CRON[49309]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)  
Feb 25 03:10:01 v4 CRON[49310]: (root) CMD (test -e /run/systemd/system || SERVICE_MODE=1 /sbin/e2scrub_all -A -r)  
Feb 25 03:10:01 v4 CRON[49309]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root  
Feb 25 03:17:01 v4 CRON[51083]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)  
Feb 25 03:17:01 v4 CRON[51084]: (root) CMD ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)  
Feb 25 03:17:01 v4 CRON[51083]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root  
Feb 25 03:24:34 v4 pmxcfs[1191]: [dcdb] notice: data verification successful  
Feb 25 03:29:04 v4 kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged  
Feb 25 03:29:04 v4 kernel: [Hardware Error]: Corrected error, no action required.  
Feb 25 03:29:04 v4 kernel: [Hardware Error]: CPU:1 (19:8:2) MC1_STATUS[Over|CE|MiscV|-|-|-|SyndV|-|-|-]: 0xd8200000060a0859  
Feb 25 03:29:04 v4 kernel: [Hardware Error]: PPIN: 0x02b68f671f2d007b  
Feb 25 03:29:04 v4 kernel: [Hardware Error]: IPID: 0x000100b000000000, Syndrome: 0x000000005a000a98  
Feb 25 03:29:04 v4 kernel: [Hardware Error]: Instruction Fetch Unit Ext. Error Code: 10, L1 BTB Multi-Match Error.  
Feb 25 03:29:04 v4 kernel: [Hardware Error]: cache level: L1, mem/io: IO, mem-tx: IRD, part-proc: SRC (no timeout)  
Feb 25 03:29:08 v4 pvedaemon[1317]: <root@pam> successful auth for user 'root@pam'  
-- Reboot --
```

```
Instruction Fetch Unit Ext. Error Code: 10, L1 BTB Multi-Match Error.
```

I was suspicious of this phrase, so I searched saw that the BIOS update on the motherboard solved the problem.

So I updated the latest version of the BIOS.

Even after updating the BIOS, the above symptoms are still like this.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to simplify things. Your phasing seems overly tech and a bit obtuse. “But the same phenomenon keeps down.” What does that mean? That it keeps coming up? Or keeps the system down? And what does this mean, “I configured Proxmox and was developing hard by launching Ubuntu LXC.”

Comment: Thank you. I read my question again and corrected it.

Comment: Here we go again... when you built it, did you take correct esd precautions? And no, touching metal every so often does not count. The errors suggest you have zapped components. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0lsHDU2Sr4 and its siblings for how much damage you can do.